# font style italic does not work in firefox sometimes

Tags: css, .htaccess, fonts

I have here a canvas where in user will enter their own message.. and have the ability to change the font, font-style and size. . all are working fine in safari, opera, chrome and ie but when it comes to firefox, it doesnt work at all. It simple do nothing, unless I disable the "**User hardware acceleration when available**" thats the time Italics works.

by the way, Im using (fonts.googleapis.com) to use the existing Css come from google.

I already used the tricks for .htaccess to solve the problem but still not works at all.

how could I fix this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it works

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("check");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "italic 40px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Impact", 0, 40);
```

Fiddle

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Apg4S/)

Try update

```
var userinputstr='';
var italic=0;
function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("check");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,50);
if(italic==0)
{
ctx.font = "40px Lato";
ctx.fillText(userinputstr, 0, 40);
}
else
{
ctx.font = "Italic 40px Lato";
ctx.fillText(userinputstr, 0, 40);
}
}
userinputstr=$("#userinput").val();
draw();
$("#userinput").keyup(function(){
userinputstr=$("#userinput").val();
draw();
});
$("#clickbut").click(function(){
italic=1;
draw();
});
```

[**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Apg4S/2/)

Comment: It works with some default fonts like (arial,georgia, ...), but when I try something like with designs. And Click on "Italic" button , the font does not do anything. But with other browsers it works.

Comment: Thanks Neophyte!! I appreciate your help!! It works on google chrome but not on mozilla .. Your code is great!! :D By the way.. im using mozilla v30.0

Comment: did you to try to see the setting for firefox under "Advance Setting - general" if the "**Use hardware acceleration when available**" is unchecked?

Comment: by default its checked. but anyhow i tried after unchecking. in this case to result is same it works...

Comment: interesting bug!! :D I dont even know why its not working on my firefox although I run you code